# Paginate a request body in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a request body in json which needs to be passed for calling another api, in this request body at max only 10 details items could be passed. Now i have 11 detail items, is there any way to paginate this request instead of copying these into two seperate request body?

```
    {
      "name": "abcd",
      "subject": {
        "Details": [
          {
            "point": "1"
          },
          {
            "point": "2"
          },
          {
            "point": "3"
          },
          {
            "point": "4"
          },
          {
            "point": "5"
          },
          {
            "point": "6"
          },
          {
            "point": "7"
          },
          {
            "point": "8"
          },
          {
            "point": "9"
          },
          {
            "point": "10"
          },
          {
            "point": "11"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: Not if the endpoint doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

You must follow the rules and standards of the api that will make the request, that is, if the api accepts up to 10 records in details, you must follow this rule, otherwise, it will probably return an error/handling message.

Comment: ya the api allows only 10 items only , not more than that. looks like i'll have to send two request.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as paginating a request. The endpoint can only accept 10 items at a time, so you'd need to send a second request

Comment: so that means i'll have to clone this request body and remove first 10 and send two request